# How to use `AVCaptureSessionPreset320x240`?

Tags: swift, avfoundation

How to use `AVCaptureSessionPreset320x240`?

```
let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset320x240

Error: Use of unresolved identifier AVCaptureSessionPreset320x240
```

Object-C:
[AVCaptureSessionPreset320x240 Source Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uf3uy.jpg)

Swift:
[AVCaptureSessionPreset320x240 Source Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNjsZ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

`AVCaptureSessionPreset` doesn't exist in 320 x 240, you can choose `AVCaptureSessionPreset352x288`. Check  [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureSession_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Video_Input_Presets)